# Is it necessary to remove stickers before gluing PVC?

Tags: plumbing

Let's say you have a piece of PVC tubing that is going into a 90 or 45 and for some reason the piece of PVC has a sticker right where the glue connection is made... will this effect the seal? Similar question for inside toilet flanges where the sticker is always in the area where the glue will be. I couldn't find any info on whether the "sticker" is compatible with the glue so to speak.

Bonus points if anyone can point me to an article or product instruction where it says that this is ok.

Comment: Will alcohol remove these stickers without softening the PVC? Prudence would dictate that these stickers should be removed before gluing.

Comment: Of course it will.  if the sticker degrades or the adhesive delaminates, boom, leak!

Answer (score 5):

Surfaces to be glued together should always be made thoroughly clean before gluing. That includes removing labels and removing any adhesive residue left by the label.

This especially applies when using solvent-welding - as is often the case for plastics used in plumbing.

Comment: It is best to sand the surfaces to be bonded.

Answer (score 0):

PVC “glue” is not glue. It is solvent cement. It works by softening the PVC and fusing together. If there is paper in the way the paper will protect the PVC from softening and you will be relying on a weak bond. If the primer is strong enough it may eat through the sticker but that has not been my experience unless the sticker has at least mostly been removed.